# Как скопировать лист PHPexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Есть шаблон .xlsx .
С помощью PHPexcel я подставляются значения в ячейки из бд и сохраняю в новом документе.

Теперь мне нужно объединить все документы.
Я думаю в сторону нескольких листов в 1 .xlsx файле.
Вот только не пойму как скопировать шаблон на другой лист.

Answer (score 1):

Показываю на примере PhpSpreadsheet-а (потомка PhpExcel).

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx as XlsxWriter;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx as XlsxReader;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;

// Подготовим таблицу, в которую мы скопируем 
// листы из существующих таблиц
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$spreadsheet->removeSheetByIndex(0);

// Ссылки на файлы ваших таблиц
$filePaths = [];

foreach ($filePaths as $key => $filePath) {
    // Достанем лист из таблицы
    $worksheet = (new XlsxReader)
        ->load($filePath)
        ->getActiveSheet()
        ->setTitle(++$key);

    // Добавим его в новую таблицу
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($worksheet);
}

// Окей, сохраним новую таблицу в файл
$writer = new XlsxWriter($spreadsheet);
$writer->save(__DIR__ . '/fileName.xlsx');
```

Comment: Вам только нужно найти замену моим классам в PhpExcel, например для считывания xlsx-файла там используется PHPExcel_IOFactory::load().